# Firebase: 3 way binding with $save for $asArray() from within the scope with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a removeFunction that splice my original model from firebase, but unfortunately that does not sync with firebase and I am not sure how to do that.

```
<a href="#{{product.title}}" ng-click="removeNode(product,brandBlock.products)">Remove</a>

$scope.removeNode=function(item,parent){
            parent.splice(parent.indexOf(item), 1);


            // Add a function here that will do something simillar with:
            // ng-blur="myCards.$save(card)" from the product title


        };
```

I want to be able to save the modified array back to firebase as this function does that is in the view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.title" ng-blur="myCards.$save(card)">
```

I know that I can nest two functions in the angular blur directive like so:

```
<a ng-click="removeNode(product,brandBlock.products); myCards.$save(card)">Remove</a>
```

but the problem is that I want to do this with some other events too that are fired only in the scope and I don't have a directive for that.

**Here is a fiddle connected to firebase:** http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/obfrraw9/

If you manage to add the removeFunction to sync and you run out of blocks, here you can add a new firebase node that you can replace in the appRef variable

http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/y0Lmc7or/

Comment: The AngularFire documentation is quite explicit: "items in the list should never be modified directly by using array methods like push() or splice()" (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html). Why can't you simply use `$remove`?

Comment: If I understand your fiddle correctly, you have nested arrays. Somehow `$remove` is not available on the child arrays. I'm not sure how to fix that, but you might want to update the question to make the fact that you're nesting arrays (and ng-repeats)  more explicit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for looking into my question. The thing is that if I do remove some items with splice and than I add a form with ng-submit=myCards.$save(card)" it will save to firebase with the items removed... or even if I do ng-click="removeNode(product,brandBlock.products); myCards.$save(card)" so the splice is working... i guess.

Comment: Frank is correct. Don't use splice() and don't use nested arrays. Both will get you into trouble (like this). Use $remove(). If you want a synchronized array of the child objects, create that.

Comment: @Kato - I am new to angular, firebase, js, everything and this is the way I imagine things should work. Why shouldn't I use nested arrays and splice()? All this code works just fine if you read and seen my comments, just that I don't know how to call that function and why that save() function only works from withing the view.... Thanks for looking into my problem dough! :)

Comment: All of this material is covered in the guide.

Comment: @Kato - I can't seem to find anything regarding nested arrays and ng-repeat. How would you recommend removing this? I just realized that splice will cause issues with firebase and they become out of sync... :(